# How to access parent member controller from child controller

Tags: controller, javafx-8

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004365/javafx-2-2-fxinclude-how-to-access-parent-controller-from-child-controller), but I need to access parent member (not control). I don't know if is possible to do without using Dependency Injection.

For example, I have a Parent with have a member calls User, I need to access from child controller to User.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just pass the reference from the parent controller to the child controller in the parent controller's `initialize()` method:

ParentController.java:

```
public class ParentController {

    @FXML
    private ChildController childController ;

    private User user ;

    public void initialize() {
        user = ...;
        childController.setUser(user);
    }
}
```

ChildController.java:

```
public class ChildController {

    private User user ;

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user ;
    }
}
```

You can also do this with JavaFX Properties instead of plain objects, if you want binding etc:

ParentController.java:

```
public class ParentController {

    @FXML
    private ChildController childController ;

    private final ObjectProperty<User> user = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(...) ;

    public void initialize() {
        user.set(...);
        childController.userProperty().bind(user);
    }
}
```

ChildController.java:

```
public class ChildController {

    private ObjectProperty<User> user = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public ObjectProperty<User> userProperty() {
        return user ;
    }
}
```

As usual, the parent fxml file needs to set the `fx:id` on the `fx:include` tag so that the loaded controller is injected to the

```
<fx:include source="/path/to/child/fxml" fx:id="child" />
```

the rule being that with `fx:id="x"`, the controller from the child fxml will be injected into a parent controller field with name `xController`.

Comment: I try with JavaFX Properties because I need binding. Thanks.

Comment: Nice SSCE of how to use fx:include and the @FXML annotation.